# How do I write a regex that says if ' string starts with BT '?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I write a regex that says, if word/string starts with the letters 'BT'?

Here's the code I working with:

```
    if(val.match(/^\S{5,}$/)){

        if(val.match(/^BT/)){

            alert('Unfortunately you cannot buy or sell registrations in the Auctions if you live in Northern Ireland');
            return false;

        }else{

            postcode.val(val.slice(0, -3)+' '+val.slice(-3));
            $('#Postcodelookup').fadeIn(300);

        }
    }else{...
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm quite new to using regex, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `/\bBT/`.

Comment: @Gumbo & Ignacio - Is there a way to customise it using JavaScript so it only picks up the BT at the begining of a word? Thanks

Comment: @Ignacio - I've added the code I'm working with but it isn't working??? Seems straightforward, what am I missing???

Comment: @Ignacio - here is what I have for `val` >  `var postcode = $(this), val = postcode.val();`

Comment: @Nasir: Uh, that's nice and all, but... WHAT IS IT?

Comment: @Nasir: Since `B` is a word character and `\b` only matched when no other word character is preceded, you could use `\WBT` to get the non-word character in front of `BT`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^BT/
```

matches if the *string* starts with `BT`. Only `BT` will be matched; if you want the match result to contain an entire word, use `/^BT\w*/`; if you want it to return the entire string, use `/^BT[\s\S]*/`.

```
/\bBT/
```

matches if a *word* starts with `BT`. Only `BT` will be matched; if you want the match result to contain the entire word, use `/\bBT\w*/`.